# Jeremy Gratton - Stillness And Forgiveness, what type of music is this?

Tags: identify-this-genre

So I stumbled upon this very particular track and I found the drums and what i believe to be sort of an Asian/Hindu style of music very soothing.

But I can't for the love of it all remember the actual genre or the name of the drums found in this track (ignore the lyrics and style of vocals) https://play.spotify.com/trackset/mediabar/7t7yA2ppYtDwJmbxN23aD8/%23/0
http://www.shazam.com/track/96319650/stillness-and-forgiveness-original

None of the media players radio function will give me anything remotely similar to this, got any example of other tracks and/or know what genre and instruments are at play here?

Comment: Progressive ethnic folk?

Comment: @Morwenn which ethnic? :)

Comment: I would say Indian. What I heard of it (only the first 30 seconds) sound like sitar and tablas, which are generally associated with Indian music. I can't say much more since I can't listen to the whole song.

Comment: @Morwenn awesome, the song isn't much different after those 30sec. It's a short track at only 1:30 or so. And it's the drums and the sitar I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Original answer March 2016, edited June 2020 to deal with dead link and correct track name.

The album notes for "Manic Melancholy", originally found on the now defunct Jeremy Gratton website, mention that the music track is from [Kevin Macleod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_MacLeod), called "Desert City". There is currently no information online from the album notes on Apple music, Amazon music, Spotify.

(quoting wikpedia article) MacLeod has composed over 2,000 pieces of royalty-free library music and made them available under a Creative Commons copyright license. There are other pieces to be found on Soundcloud and Youtube using the the same piece. "Identification of library music" is generally ruled off-topic here, see [discussion on meta](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/467/dealing-with-identify-youtuber-video-soundtrack-questions). Kevin Macleod seems like an exception, since his aim is to "an alternate body of works that is able to compete with [the existing broken copyright system]" (adapted from Wikipedia entry).

From the notes to ["Desert City"](https://incompetech.filmmusic.io/song/3639-desert-city/) : on KM's "incompetech" website,

- "Middle Eastern atmospheric, sort of chill. This piece is easy to
  loop."
- "Genres : World"
- "Moods: Dreamy  Elegant  Grooving  Mysterious
  Relaxed  Serious  Suspenseful"

Comment: That's perfect! I'm ashamed that my google-detective-skills didn't gather this information myself, hehe. But I thank you for this, so awesome!

Comment: thanks for that, I kind of like the thrill of the chase, with finding things out, so thanks for a good question

Comment: Ok, thanks for spotting. I need another source for the album notes to 'Manic melancholy'